# PostgreSQL - return table with array columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, join

I need an SQL function to return a table with some regular columns and some array columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_some_properties(...)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        someText    TEXT,
        someBool    BOOLEAN,
        someInt     INTEGER,
        propID      INTEGER[],
        propVal     TEXT[]
    ) AS
...
```

The properties retrieved are stored in two tables: one for the scalar values - `someText`, `someBool`, `someInt`; and another one for the arrays.
They are connected by some global key.

```
select * from Table1 where key_column= MyGlobalKey;
select * from Table2 where key_column= MyGlobalKey;
```

So back to my question. How would I convert the results of the second query (`Table2`) to the arrays `propID` and `propVal` and return the result.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    key_column      INTEGER,  -- key_column is a primary key here, hence unique
    someText        TEXT,
    someBool        BOOLEAN,
    someInt         INTEGER
    ...

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    key_column      INTEGER,  -- key_column is not unique here
    prop_id         INTEGER,
    prop_val        TEXT,
    ...
```

Comment: Have you tried what you have written? It works. What language (other than SQL) are you using?

Comment: What happens when you try the second query? What should happen instead?

Comment: My explanation was misleading. Sorry. What I meant to say was that the second table has the values stored as regular rows, so the problem is converting those rows to a single row of array type, and then join that to the first table...

Answer (score 2):

OK, found a way. something along the lines of:

```
SELECT someText, someBool, someInt 
     , array(SELECT prop_id  FROM Table2 WHERE key_column = mykey)
     , array(SELECT prop_val FROM Table2 WHERE key_column = mykey)
FROM Table1 WHERE key_column = mykey
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) the two tables.

Using a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` in my example, assuming you always want values from table1 for the given `MyGlobalKey`, and only add values from table2, if they exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_some_properties(_myglobalkey int)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        someText text,
        someBool boolean,
        someInt  integer,
        propID   integer[],
        propVal  text[]
    ) AS
$func$
SELECT t1.someText, t1.someBool, t1.someInt
      ,t2.propID, t2.propVal
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 USING (key_column)
WHERE  t1.key_column = $1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Of course, this should be a 1:1 relationship, or you may get multiple combined rows. SQL basics, [details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM).